# NLog - How to apply header & footer layout for archive files?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Using NLog's(v4.0.1) archiving feature and its header & footer layout options, I expected each generated archive file to contain this structure: `[header]-[body]-[footer]`

But instead, what's actually generated is the following structure without a footer:
`[header]-[body]` and only for the ***first*** created file. All the subsequent files are made ***without*** any header or footer - seems like all archived files are just pieces of the main log file.

This is my configuration:

```
<nlog
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
      <targets>
        <target
          xsi:type="File"
          name="file"
          fileName="${basedir}/logs/NLogTest.txt"
          layout="${message}"
          header="--------------Header"
          footer="--------------Footer"
          archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/NLogTest_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm}.{#}.txt"
          archiveNumbering="Sequence"
          archiveAboveSize="300"
          archiveEvery="Minute"
          maxArchiveFiles="99999">
        </target>
      </targets>
      <rules>
        <logger
          name="fileLogger"
          minlevel="Trace"
          writeTo="file" />
      </rules>
    </nlog>
```

My c# log writing code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started");
    var fileLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("fileLogger");
    while (true)
    {
        fileLogger.Info("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```